# Output month with highest cancellations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am able to get the count of cancelled members for every month since 2018 using the below query -

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, Cancel) [Year],
DATEPART(Month, Cancel) [Month], COUNT(1) [Count]
FROM Subscription
where DATEPART(YEAR, Cancel) >= 2018
GROUP BY DATEPART(year, Cancel),DATEPART(Month, Cancel)
ORDER BY 1,2
```

The output is

```
Year    Month    Count
2018    1        6416775
2018    2        458171
2018    3        29963575
2018    4        65393505
```

How do I modify this query so it displays only the month that has the most cancellations?

**UPDATE**

This is the output I want. Each year should have the highest `Count` value outputted.

```
Year    Month    Count
2018    4        65393505
2019    2        458171
```

Month 4 in 2018 was outputted because it had the highest value when compared to the first 4 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like below by using `row_number()`

```
with cte as
(
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, Cancel) [Year],
DATEPART(Month, Cancel) [Month], COUNT(1) [Count]
FROM Subscription
where DATEPART(YEAR, Cancel) >= 2018
GROUP BY DATEPART(year, Cancel),DATEPART(Month, Cancel)
ORDER BY 1,2
)
,cte1 as
( select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( partition by [Year] ORDER BY [Count] DESC) rn  from cte
) select * from cte1 where rn=1
```

Comment: This is not what I need. I need 1 record for every year. This is producing more than 1 record for a particular year.

Comment: Edited answer just remove month from partition

Answer (score 2):

Using `order by count desc` and selecting the first record by `top 1` you can get the desired output:

```
SELECT TOP 1 DATEPART(YEAR, Cancel) [Year],
DATEPART(Month, Cancel) [Month], COUNT(1) [Count]
FROM Subscription
where DATEPART(YEAR, Cancel) >= 2018
GROUP BY DATEPART(year, Cancel),DATEPART(Month, Cancel)
ORDER BY Count DESC
```

Comment: This is not what I need. I have updated my question to clarify.

Comment: @Aaron check my answer please

Comment: This is not what I need. I need 1 record for every year.

Answer (score 0):

TRY Following

`SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, Cancel) [Year], DATEPART(Month, Cancel) [Month], COUNT(1) [Count]
      FROM Subscription
      WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, Cancel) >= 2018
      GROUP BY DATEPART(year, Cancel),DATEPART(Month, Cancel)
      ORDER BY 1,2) as Table1
WHERE Count = (SELECT MAX COUNT(1) [Count]
               FROM Subscription
               WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, Cancel) >= 2018
               GROUP BY DATEPART(year, Cancel),DATEPART(Month, Cancel)
               ORDER BY 1,2)`

Comment: This is not what I need. I need 1 record for every year. This is producing more than 1 record for a particular year.

Comment: Is this `ORDER BY 1,2` serving any purpose in your query?

Comment: It is ordering the results by Year and Month.